# does copying a div duplicate a form

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a div on my page that acts as a shell to store other divs. The page loads and the shell is hidden & empty. 
On a jQuery event I show the shell and fill it with the triggered div.
More often than not, the triggered div happens to be a form.

if I do this:

```
$('#lb_content').html($('#' + div_id).html());
```

that duplicates the form and makes validation/submit difficult - **right?**

---

my work around is to store an global variable:

```
var container_emptied = '';
```

so when I show the shell I do this:

```
var content = $('#' + div_id).html();
container_emptied = '#' + div_id;
$(container_emptied).empty();
$('#lb_content').html(content);
```

and when I hide the shell I do this:

```
$(container_emptied).html($('#lb_content').html());
$('#lb_content').empty();
```

am I over complicating this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems like you're just moving the form content from one location to another. Is that right?

If so, just use `.appendTo()` like this:

```
    // Move all the content to new location
$('#' + div_id).contents().appendTo('#lb_content');
```

and do the opposite to move it back:

```
    // Move all the content back
$('#lb_content').contents().appendTo('#' + div_id);
```

(I assume you were only interested in the content, and not the element itself.)

**EDIT:** Reversed the two. Had them backward the first time.

- http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/
- http://api.jquery.com/contents/